# how to select element parent-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, parent-child

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="home_box">
    <a href="#">
        <img alt="" src="/10829_rf-sicherheit/images/home_boxes/home1.jpg">
        <span class="box_caption" style="bottom: 0px;">
            <span class="box_title">Sicherheit</span>
            <span class="box_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor ...</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to access the .box_text when the link is hovered

Something like this in css

```
div.home_box a span.home_caption span.box_text {opacity:1;}
```

But this doesnt seem to work?!

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Isn't it just `.home_box a:hover .box_text` ? Your css is not working because you are not targeting the hover state and you don't have home_caption anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you:

```
div.home_box a span.box_caption span.box_text {
    opacity:1;
}
```

You write `home_caption` in your CSS and `box_caption` in your HTML

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to fix both the incorrect class and the missing `:hover` pseudo class to make it work properly:

```
div.home_box a:hover span.box_caption span.box_text {
    opacity:1;
}
```

**Note:**

Opacity is not supported in all browsers without some vendor prefixes. In order to accomodate the maximum number of browsers, you'll need to add some additional CSS:

```
div.home_box a:hover span.box_caption span.box_text {
    /* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */
    /* ...or something to trigger hasLayout, like zoom: 1; */
    width: 100%; 

    /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
    /* ...but not required as filter works too */
    /* should come BEFORE filter */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";

    /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
    /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);

    /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;

    /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
    -khtml-opacity: 1.0;

    /* Modern!
    /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
    /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

**Source:** [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)

**Disclaimer:** The above snippet came directly from CSS Tricks with two modification being. The first modification was the substitution of their `.transparent` selector for yours to make a complete snippet. The second was the changing of the opacity values to support your request of `1`.

Comment: It's 2014. I honestly don't think any of these extra properties are necessary anymore (even `-ms-filter` as an exception is debatable). If you still need to go through all the trouble to support non-IE browsers that came out ten years ago (before Firefox 1.0 was released and before WebKit came to existence), I pity you.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using `a:hover span.home_caption span.box_text {opacity: 1;}`

Right now you're just specifying the a tag in general, not when it's being hovered.